# Can i turn my Old 2009 Imac into a Multi-use NAS server?

Tags: network, hardware, server.app, nas

I have a late 2009 imac, everything is perfectly fine with the machine. Can i turn that into a Media/ NAS server?

Comment: I think that the general answer is "yes". But, as always, the details are what matters. Can you clarify your request a bit more? Perhaps a bit more specifically about what you are trying to do - and potentially what you've already looked into using? You will likely get a much better response if you can provide more details...

Comment: To start, take a look at Plex (https://plex.tv) for media, and as for NAS, you can use AFP or SMB which can be activated in OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.

1. Give that Mac a static IP on your home network.
2. Locate it near your home router so you can connect it to the router by Ethernet cable for stability and performance.
3. Set its power settings to never sleep.
4. Turn off or uninstall all unnecessary applications.
5. Think about what users/account settings you will use to allow access.
6. Set suitable ACL permissions on the directory you will use for the NAS root storage path.
7. Turn on AFP, SMB, or NFS sharing as needed.

You now have a basic NAS.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using my early 2009 iMac as a Plex Media server since it was released.  The specs are 2.93Ghz Core2Duo with 4GB of memory.  I use it with a wired Gigabit ethernet connection in tandem with three 2TB Western Digital Mybook Live NAS units.  I have all the media on SMB shares that are mounted on the iMac as a login item in OS X.  The configuration works well, and I share the server with about 20 people and support all 4 TVs in my house plus about 3-5 concurrent remote streams.  I do notice that it taxes the CPU, but my remote users have no complaints of buffering issues.  I also have a 25mb upload through my ISP which is helpful.  Good luck.  Your iMac should work well for what you are looking to do.